# jquery.inputmask unmasking empty email

Tags: jquery

I am using RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask library.

Library returning `_@_._` for empty value.
You can try [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/75q8xwcf/5/). Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="email" autocomplete="off">
<button type="button" id="unmask">Unmask</button><br>
Value: '<span id="val"></span>'<br>
Unmasked value: '<span id="unmasked"></span>'
```

JS:

```
$("#email").inputmask('email');
$("#email").inputmask({'autoUnmask': true});

$("#unmask").click(function(){
    $("#val").text($("#email").val());
    $("#unmasked").text($("#email").inputmask('unmaskedvalue'));
});
```

Comment: What's your main objective here?

Comment: I want obtain unmasked value even entered empty email.

Comment: You want to get this expected output: (e.g `''`) instead of this `_@_._`?

Comment: Yes. I want unmasked value from empty input `''`

Comment: Have you've solve this problem now?

Comment: Nope. Maybe library bugged... `autoUnmask` does not work.

Comment: Kindly check the answer I've posted below

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it stills get the given `automask email pattern`, One of the workarounds I would recommend is to find a given `regex pattern`  and replace it to an empty string. This is to get and check if the given value is an empty string or note.

Given Example:

```
$("#email").inputmask('email');
$("#email").inputmask({
    'autoUnmask': true
});

$("#unmask").click(function() {
    var oEmailText = $("#email");
    $("#val").text(oEmailText.val());
    $("#unmasked").text(oEmailText.val());
    var sInitialValue = $.trim(oEmailText.val()).replace(/^[\s_@.]+$/g, '');

    $("#unmasked").text(sInitialValue);
    if ($.trim(sInitialValue) === '') {
        alert('Empty value');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here's a JS Fiddle for further reference: http://jsfiddle.net/7o5sn8bf/

Hope this helps for your case.

PS : Though I would suggest that its okay not import the given mask library plugin if you are applying the [auto mask inputs] for [email inputs] only https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Comment: Sorry, but it is like a kludge and applicable only for `email` mask. For other masks need fix `regex pattern`. Any way thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution without regexp and etc. Looks like library bugged and `autoUnmask` does not work. Redifine `onUnMask` give correct result.

JS code here:

```
$("#email").inputmask("email", { onUnMask: function(maskedValue, unmaskedValue) {
    return unmaskedValue;
}});
```

Here is fixed [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/75q8xwcf/7/).

Comment: Not working for correct email. It will remove `@` and `.` symbols.